# I receive: firebase.database is not a function error when trying to connect my form to the database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to connect my contact form to a firebase database and i keep getting the firebase.database is not a function error continuously. 
I'm also using parcel-bundler for this project and also getting these errors:

```
at Object.parcelRequire.firebase.js (firebase.js:44)
    at newRequire (firebase.js:44)
    at firebase.js:44
    at firebase.js:44
```

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong, after looking at similar problems none of them could provide a solution.

This is how I am linking my files:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.0.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="./firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="./main.js"></script>
  </body>
```

This is the code from my firebase.js file:

```
// Your web app's Firebase configuration
var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaS*************r48uEU",
  authDomain: "k********irebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://*******irebaseio.com",
  projectId: "k******",
  storageBucket: "k**********m",
  messagingSenderId: "984****903",
  appId: "1:9843179**********3734705af"
};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

var messageRef = firebase.database().ref("messages");

//grab a form
document.querySelector(".contact-form").addEventListener("submit", submitForm);

function submitForm(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // get values
  var name = getInputVal("name");
  var email = getInputVal("email");
  var number = getInputVal("phone");
  var message = getInputVal("message");

  saveMessage(name, email, number, message);
}

function getInputVal(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id).value;
}

function saveMessage(name, email, number, message) {
  var newMessageRef = messageRef.push();

  newMessageRef.set({
    name: name,
    email: email,
    number: number,
    message: message
  });
}
```

Any help will be deeply appreciated, thanks guys.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the code in `firebase.js` so people can help you solve the problem?

Comment: try adding `<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.1.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>` to your script tags

Comment: I tried, but unfortunately no luck, still getting the errors.

Comment: my apologies, the script i linked is for an older version, maybe try this one `<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.0.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>` ?

Comment: Yes i realised it was outdated but you were on the right track there. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad i could help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're currently only including this for Firebase:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.0.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
```

This only contains the definition of `FirebaseApp`, and doesn't include Firebase Authentication (`firebase.auth()`) or Firebase Realtime Database (`firebase.database()`). To include those, be sure to include the correct scripts for that too:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.0.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.0.2/firebase-database.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much! It worked!!. Most of the references i could find on this were fairly outdated and even though I am good with reading documentation the firebase documentation really confused me. Everything is working great now and messages are going to the database, however i am still getting an error: ```Uncaught Error: Network Error
    at iframewrapper.js:124``` Is this something i should worry about?